# count occurrences of sets

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to count the occurances of a value in column b and group by column a:

IE If I had the following data:

```
A     B
1     2
1     3
1     2
1     4
2     2
2     3
2     2
2     4
```

I would like to return the following:

```
A     B     C
1     2     2
1     3     1
1     2     2
1     4     1
2     2     2
2     3     1
2     2     2
2     4     1
```

Ok. I am sorry that I didn't add what I had tried. It's Monday and it was a rough 4th of July Week. My Aunt passed from Cancer while I was in the hospital room with her.

SELECT a, 
       b, 
       C = Count(*) 
             OVER ( 
               partition BY b) 
FROM   yourtable;

I don't know why I didn't try

SELECT a, 
       b, 
       C = Count(*) 
             OVER ( 
               partition BY a, b) 
FROM   yourtable;

As suggested or simply join on a sub query. I guess it is just one of those off days. This question can be deleted.

Comment: Questions **must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Hmm 5 upvotes for the Fresh to close and only 3 close votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
SELECT a, 
       b, 
       C = Count(*) 
             OVER ( 
               partition BY a, b) 
FROM   yourtable;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa400/3)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a correlated subquery to get the result:

```
SELECT a, b,
  (select count(*)
   from yourtable t1
   where t.a = t1.a
     and t.b = t1.b) c
FROM yourtable t
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa400/4)